# nx.hits shows OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, scipy, networkx

Please see code below

```
   #HITS
nx.hits(G, max_iter=9999999999)

# Finding Hubs & Authorities. Outputs in a dictionary format
hubs, authorities = nx.hits(G, normalized=False) 
# removed the default normalization because it normalizes hubs from a range of 1 to 5 only.
```

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` is a collection of algorithms for interacting with `numpy` arrays. Under the hood, a lot of `numpy`'s implementation is written in C, and therefore it is somewhat limited by the capabilities of C. In this case, it is trying to convert a Python `int` into a C `int`, which unlike Python's `int` type have a limited range (up to `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`). Your value for `max_iter` is greater than the maximum value that C supports, and therefore it fails to call the function you require since it can't perform the conversion.